# virtualbox, can't mouse scroll if 3D acceleration is enabled

Tags: unity, virtualbox, mouse, scrolling

I'm trying out Ubuntu 14.04 for the first time with virtual box in windows 8.  I've noticed that when I enable 3D acceleration I'm no longer able to scroll with my mouse wheel.  When I tried scrolling in xev no events were fired.  If I disable 3D acceleartion and do the same everything works as expected.  I've installed guest additions through virtualbox menu but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: To install guest additions we in addition to select it from the menu in VBox manager (this only mounts the GA iso to the guest) we also have to run the installer script on the guest additions CD .iso. I have no idea if that will resolve the mouse wheel issue. On my systems all mouse events are passed to the guests without any issue.

Comment: Hi Takkat, thanks for the reply.  Guest additions was installed successfully but I still have not mouse scrolling.  I've tried creating a virtual box with 14.10 and I have the same issue.  I also tried installing virtual box extension pack, but still doesn't work.  I'm enjoying Ubuntu so far but this issue is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

My mouse wheel is working again.  Updated to the latest nvidia drivers and also did a Windows update.  Because I did both at the same time I can't say which fixed it but if someone else is experiencing this issue perhaps try udpating the host's drivers.